# Error when running "docker-compose build solution" from sitecore 10 docker guide

Tags: powershell, docker

I'm at [this stage of the guide](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/100/developer-tools/build-sitecore-solutions.html#build-the-solution-image_body) whereby I'm required to build a solution from `custom-images` directory.

After running `docker-compose build solution` from the directory, it throws the below error at step 3.

[image]

My Dockerfile is as follows...

```
# escape=`

ARG BASE_IMAGE
ARG BUILD_IMAGE

FROM ${BUILD_IMAGE} AS prep
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 
'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Gather only artifacts necessary for NuGet restore, retaining directory structure
COPY *.sln nuget.config Directory.Build.targets Packages.props \nuget\
COPY src\ \temp\
RUN Invoke-Expression 'robocopy C:\temp C:\nuget\src /s /ndl /njh /njs *.csproj *.scproj 
packages.config'

FROM ${BUILD_IMAGE} AS builder

ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 
'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Create an empty working directory
WORKDIR C:\build

# Copy prepped NuGet artifacts, and restore as distinct layer to take better advantage 
of caching
COPY --from=prep .\nuget .\
RUN nuget restore

# Copy remaining source code
COPY src\ .\src\

# Copy transforms, retaining directory structure
RUN Invoke-Expression 'robocopy C:\build\src C:\out\transforms /s /ndl /njh /njs *.xdt'

# Build website with file publish
RUN msbuild .\src\DockerExamples.Website\DockerExamples.Website.csproj 
/p:Configuration=$env:BUILD_CONFIGURATION /p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem 
/p:PublishUrl=C:\out\website

# Build XConnect with file publish
RUN msbuild .\src\DockerExamples.XConnect\DockerExamples.XConnect.csproj 
/p:Configuration=$env:BUILD_CONFIGURATION /p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem 
/p:PublishUrl=C:\out\xconnect

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}

WORKDIR C:\artifacts

# Copy final build artifacts
COPY --from=builder C:\out\website .\website\
COPY --from=builder C:\out\transforms .\transforms\
COPY --from=builder C:\out\xconnect .\xconnect\
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the know the problem caused if outdated network storage drivers.

Take a look here: https://github.com/microsoft/hcsshim/issues/624

Try to install fresh SFTP Drive V2 drivers or uninstall Box, One Drive or any other network drive you have installed on your system and try again (after restarting PC).

Comment: interesting, thanks will update and report back

Comment: Removed one drive, don't have box. Also checked that thread and the problem driver is not present on my system. Very frustrating

Comment: @SeanT All windows updates installed?

Comment: I'm on windows version 20H2, build 19042.1165. I work for a university so all the pc's have managed os's unfortunately - we are likely slightly behind. I think you are right though hcsshim is a windows lib.

Comment: Did you try to install new [SFTP Drive V2 drivers](https://www.google.com/search?q=SFTP+Drive+V2+drivers+exe&oq=SFTP+Drive+V2+drivers+exe&aqs=edge..69i57.4102j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: Yep - no different. Have since removed, I'm in the process of trying with a 11/2020 release of docker (3.0)